# Writing to a DBF decimal field with vba ADO connection

Tags: vba, adodb, dbf

I'm trying to add a new record to a DBF table using ADODB connection in VBA. There are numeric (decimal) fields which size were set at 4 at table construction and I can't write to those.

Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)': The size of a field is too long.
I've tried to push all types of vba variable no avail. Only Null works.

- Recordset fields properties:
- Recordset.DefinedSize returns 8
- Recordset.Type returns adDouble

```
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBF.Path & ";Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"
sql = "SELECT * FROM " & Left(DBF.Name, (InStrRev(DBF.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))
rs.CursorType = 1
rs.Open sql, con, , 3
With rs
    .addNew
    .Fields("SIZE_4_FIELD") = myVar 'tried all types
End With
rs.Update
```

I tried manually as suggested by @Alex K.

```
con.Execute "insert into myTable (SIZE_4_Field) values ('123')" 'Field too long Error
con.Execute "insert into myTable (Other_Field) values ('123')" 'Works
con.Execute "insert into myTable (SIZE_4_Field) values (123)" 'Field too long Error
con.Execute "insert into myTable (SIZE_4_Field) values (Null)" 'Works
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it manually? `con.execute "insert into your_dbf_file_name (SIZE_4_FIELD) values (123)"`

Comment: Would help to show some actual examples of what you tried.

Comment: @AlexK.Thanks, i gave it a try manually. Same error. It works to other fields. Only the fields which were created with a custom byte size fail.

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, I just edited with the Alex suggestion. First step seems to be able to do it directly.Cheers.